# Google extension index.html wont show the text that I replaced

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fetch-api

-edited

My extension is basically receive the text that selected/highlighted by user to translate and save the word

I need to check the user selected text and then replaced it on html  textContent which is my pop up windows

If the i use fetchDataHandle('text'), it will work since it's a string but if it's a variable it wont work meaning it wont replace the  textContent

I tried to change `data[0].word` to the text refer to fetchDataHandle but it doesn't work

I tested and the data[0].word is not empty even if it's variable so Im confused why it doesn't work
Here my code
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html {
        min-height: 5em;
        min-width: 10em;
        background: rgba(250, 128, 114, 0);
      }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="word"></h2>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

content.js:

```
async function fetchDataHandle(text){
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${text}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    document.getElementById("word").textContent = `${data[0].word}`;
    }

text = getSelection().toString()
fetchDataHandle(text)
```

background.js:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ["content.js"]
  });
  });
```

if the i use fetchDataHandle('text'), it will work
but if it's a variable it wont
I tested and the data[0].word is not empty even if it's variable so im confused why it doesn't work

Comment: 1. What exactly is the data you receive? 2. What do you mean by "doesn't work" - what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for ur reply. So for the first question what exactly is the data you receive, I receive the text that selected/highlighted by user. And for the second question, the doesn't work meant by the value (data[0].word) wont replace the <h2 id='word'></h2> because if it replaced successful it suppose to print out the value, but it doesn't. It only replaced when the function fetchDataHandle(input) input is a String but not a variable

Comment: I also edited the original post to make it clear, you can read it again see if you can understand what i tryna do